# Port is added to IP table but why not listening?

Tags: linux, bash, collectd

I have two centos Machine, Machine A and Machine B. In machine A i have installed collectd and influxdb. So, the system metric from machine A is pushed into influxdb using collectd. I have installed collectd in machine B. Now, I need to push the system metric from machine B to the influxdb which is in machine A.

Collectd uses the port 25826.

I have added the port 25826 in the iptable of machine B.ANd i restarted the iptable...But its not listening...

Can anyone help please...

Answer (score 0):

CentOS uses firewalld to manage iptables.

Provided you have firewalld installed and active, just add the port to the permanent open ports table:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=25826/udp
```

Then reload the firewalld config:

```
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Now you can check that the port is open on the machine with:

```
firewall-cmd --list-ports
```

Edit: fix the rule to be 25826/udp

Comment: collectd sends data in udp packets, not tcp. Should be: firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=25826/udp